# Silverlight 4 application on localhost runs extremely slow

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Silverlight 4 app running in IE8 and hosted on VS2010 internal webserver. The website takes atleast a minute to download the xap and code runs slow on client (IE8). I am running the app in debug mode and have turned intellitrace off. Symbol loading is also turned off.

However if I kill the VS webserver, clean the solution, the app runs fast. 3 debugging sessions later, the app slows to a crawl.

Have also tried turning off McAfee live scanning but no use. Looked in event log for any clue but found none.

What could be the cause of the slowness?

TIA
rams

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed a similar problem. What I notice in particular in my case is an increase in memory from what the normal memory usage would be server-side.

For me, the only way out is to kill the server-side process. In your case, this would be the web server in Visual Studio.

You could try hosting the service in IIS instead, and setting the Disable Overlapped Recycle option. I believe that the answer is in the Application Pool options somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have been killing the web server and relaunching the app often. It works but its annoying. Like to understand the root cause and fix it.